# What components work better when they warm up? (apart from vacuum tubes)

Tags: temperature, heat, thermal, reliability

Conventional wisdom is that heat is bad for electronics. Metals and most doped semiconductors conduct more poorly, and everything ages faster.

But in my experience, some faulty appliances don't work when I first turn them on, but start working after a while, presumably due to warming up. I don't mean ancient amplifiers with vacuum tubes in them, but a modern PC and flatscreen TV. Both had some bad electrolytic capacitors in them and replacing two of those fixed the TV (I didn't bother with the PC - too old), but that doesn't necessarily mean the caps were benefiting from warmth - some other component might have been working better when it warmed up and compensating for the bad caps.

So my question is, what are the components (either perfect or degraded with age) that work better when they warm up? (I already know about vacuum tubes AKA valves)

Comment: Voltage and frequency references.

Comment: We saw cases where a faulty cold solder joint made a better contact because of thermal expansion.  A cold solder joint is not a component, though.  [Having said that, I'm not convinced that this question is on-topic for EE.SE .  It's not too far from *use* or *repair* questions.]

Comment: Warm up relative to? Room temp? Because most electronics will also stop working at -50C or below.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff yes, relative to room temp.

Comment: @NickAlexeev if off-topic here, where would it be on-topic?

Comment: Energy saving light bulbs. Also precision measuring instruments like spectrum analysers. Lewis Hamiltons brake discs.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams voltage and frequency references are rather general concepts. Did you have particular components in mind?

Comment: The ovened ones are obvious, but even exposed ones are more stable once they reach a (relatively) stable temperature.

Comment: I'd expect some electrolytic capacitors to have trouble far above -50C - Water based electrolytes will eventually freeze, no?

Answer (score 1):

A diode will have lower threshold voltage when hotter - which is desirable in eg a rectifier since you will incur less loss, or when a device only has a limited voltage budget eg for a LED.

Answer (score 0):

Power semiconductor switches (e.g. IGBTs) have higher switching overvoltage (but low switching losses) when their junction is on low temperature (room temperature). From the viewpoint of overvoltage and the resulting stress, the device performance is better on high operating temperature. Of course, it is just the opposite concerning losses.

Answer (score 0):

TCXOs and OCXOs (temperature-/oven-controlled crystal oscillators) must reach their working temperature before they'll run at the proper frequency. The same principle may apply to other oscillators, albeit less intentionally.